# visual foxpro 98 working with cursores and brows, and loop for, for add columns

Tags: cursor, foxpro, visual-foxpro

```
*!*          TransForm(m.TCuatro,"@Z 999,999,999") + " "
*!*  CDate("mx",Val(Right(Allt(field(4,"_Actual")),2)),Val("20"+SubStr(Allt(field(3,"_Actual")),2,2))) + " N(15,2)," + ;
*!*           CDate("mx",Val(Right(Allt(field(5,"_Actual")),2)),Val("20"+SubStr(Allt(field(4,"_Actual")),2,2))) + " N(15,2)," + 
CadExel = CDate("mx",Val(Right(Allt(field(2,"_Actual")),2)),Val("20"+SubStr(Allt(field(2,"_Actual")),2,2))) + " N(15,2)," + ;         
          "Promedio N(15,2), " + ;
          "Cuota" + CDate("mx",__Mes,__Ano) + " N(12), " + ;
          "VsProm N(12,2), " + ;
          "Dobles N(12), Triples N(12), Fuera C(6)"
*!*           CDate("mx",Val(Right(Allt(field(6,"_Actual")),2)),Val("20"+SubStr(Allt(field(5,"_Actual")),2,2))) + " N(12),"
*!*           Padl(CDate("mx",Val(Right(Allt(field(4,"_Actual")),2)),Val("20"+SubStr(Allt(field(4,"_Actual")),2,2))),14) + " " + ;
*!*           Padl(CDate("mx",Val(Right(Allt(field(5,"_Actual")),2)),Val("20"+SubStr(Allt(field(5,"_Actual")),2,2))),14) + " " + 
TitNF   = Padl(CDate("mx",Val(Right(Allt(field(3,"_Actual")),2)),Val("20"+SubStr(Allt(field(3,"_Actual")),2,2))),14) + " " + ;
          Padl("Promedio",14) + " " + ;
          Padl("Cuota",11) + " " + ;
          Padl("VsAA",11) + " " + ;
          Padl("Dobles",11) + " " + ;
          Padl("Triples",11) + " " + ;
          Padl("Rango",5) + " " 
*!*           Padl(CDate("mx",Val(Right(Allt(field(6,"_Actual")),2)),Val("20"+SubStr(Allt(field(6,"_Actual")),2,2))),11) + " "

Select * From __Cadena Order By Que Into Cursor __Paso
Select __Cadena
Zap
Select __Paso
   Cad = "insert into __Cadena Values ( "
   For i= 1 To FCount()
      Cad = Cad + "__Paso." + Allt(Field(i,"__Paso")) + ","
   EndFor
   Cad = Left(Cad,Len(Cad)-1) + ")"
Go Top
Do While !Eof()
   &Cad
   Select __Paso
   Skip    
EndDo
Select __Paso
Use

*!* Set ClassLib To MyTool
*!* Barra = CreateObject("MiBarra")
*!* Barra.Dock(0)
*!* Barra.Show

*!* Define Class MiBarra As MyToolBar
*!* EndDefine
*!* Read Events
Select __Cadena
Go Top
Do vfreport With "Premier", TitNF , " Cuotas Club-Premier" + " de " + cDate("my",__Mes,__Ano) + IIf(__EsCF," (CF)"," (UV) "),"("+Allt(m.xNomPunto)+")",  "Cuotas",;
   CadExel,"",.F.,.F.,1,1,2,1,.F.,.F.,0
```

well that code is the final part for create this:
[image]

so you could see a column call a column call "mar08" which is 
Marzo 2008 or "march 2008", well at this example i have a column,
but in part of code it gets to have 3 ór plus columns so i need add this lines for every column:

this code for a new column

```
CDate("mx",Val(Right(Allt(field(3,"_Actual")),2)),Val("20"+SubStr(Allt(field(2,"_Actual")),2,2))) + " N(12)," + ;
```

and this code for data of this column

```
Padl(CDate("mx",Val(Right(Allt(field(3,"_Actual")),2)),Val("20"+SubStr(Allt(field(3,"_Actual")),2,2))),11) + " " + ;
```

my question is

How can i do a loop for, for  add automatically the code for columns, and data?

i am newbie on visual fox 98

Comment: I can probably help, but this code is really ugly...  I can follow it, but still ugly.  Can you list the structure of the table where the raw data is coming from.  Also, dump about 10 rows of the data you are trying to get totals from and show your grid expanded.  It appears you are using a customized grid control with the "+" indicating an expand/collapse of additional data.

Comment: There's no such thing as 'Visual FoxPro 98' either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking here is how you might do it...

```
CadExel = ""
TitNF = ""
FOR X = 1 TO n (where n is the number of columns you want to add)
    CadExel = CadExel + CDate("mx",Val(Right(Allt(field(3,"_Actual")),2)),Val("20"+SubStr(Allt  (field(2,"_Actual")),2,2))) + " N(12),"
    TitNF = TitNF + Padl(CDate("mx",Val(Right(Allt(field(3,"_Actual")),2)),Val("20"+SubStr(Allt(field(3,"_Actual")),2,2))),11) + " "
ENDFOR

CadExel = CadExel + ; 
    "Promedio N(15,2), " + ;
      "Cuota" + CDate("mx",__Mes,__Ano) + " N(12), " + ;
      "VsProm N(12,2), " + ;
      "Dobles N(12), Triples N(12), Fuera C(6)"
TitNF = TitNF + ;
      Padl("Promedio",14) + " " + ;
      Padl("Cuota",11) + " " + ;
      Padl("VsAA",11) + " " + ;
      Padl("Dobles",11) + " " + ;
      Padl("Triples",11) + " " + ;
      Padl("Rango",5) + " "
```

Basically you would concatenate your columns into CadEx and your column data into TitNF from within a FOR loop.  'X' is the variable that gets incremented on every iteration so you might need to use that somewhere within the CadExel and TitNF variables to change a portion of the expression.

If I am way off on this then maybe this will at least give you an idea of on how use the FOR loop to build the column and column data you are looking for.